# Why did it take 11(ish) years to make Deadpool?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, marvel, deadpool, production, deadpool-2016

According to several stories regarding the just released Deadpool movie, it is stated Ryan Reynolds (who had played a previous version of Deadpool) had to wait 11 years to play the main character in the Deadpool film. Why did it take 11(ish) years after the release of *[X-Men Origins: Wolverine](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0458525/)* to make *[Deadpool](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1431045/)*?

Comment: Because they were making other films in the meantime.

Comment: Ryan Reynolds had to learn how to be funny.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because it was in [development hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Development_hell).

To be precise, it was in development from 2000, making it 16 years. But there were various reason at various levels. Here are the bullet points of it from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadpool_(film)#Development):-

> - May 2000, Artisan Entertainment announced a deal with Marvel Entertainment to coproduce, finance and distribute a film based on
>   Deadpool.
> - 2004, New Line Cinema attempted to produce a Deadpool film with writer/director David S. Goyer working on the spin-off and actor Ryan
>   Reynolds.
> - By August, Goyer lost interest in favor of other projects.
> - In March 2005, after New Line put Deadpool in turnaround, 20th Century Fox became interested in moving forward on production for the
>   project.
> - Fox considered a Deadpool spin-off early in the development of X-Men Origins: Wolverine, with Reynolds cast in the role, and after the
>   opening weekend success of that film announced that it was lending
>   Deadpool out to writers, with Lauren Shuler Donner acting as a
>   producer. Donner wanted the film to reboot the character of Deadpool,
>   ignoring the version and giving more justice to comic version with
>   breaking the fourth wall.
> - Rhett Reese and Paul Wernick were hired to write the script in January 2010.
> - The script leaked in the February of 2010 and garnered a positive reaction by the fans, prompting Fox to grant a small budget for test
>   footage.
> - In July 2014, the visual effects test footage created for the film in 2012 and starring Reynolds through motion capture, was leaked
>   online. Blur Studio, the company that created the test footage,
>   subsequently released it officially.
> - In September 2014, Fox gave the film a release date of February 12, 2016

So in short, it was delayed because of Goyer's disinterest, studio change etc etc. But the leaks were too much responsible to there greenlight of the project.

Comment: I read somewhere that the poor reception of *Green Lantern* in 2011 made the studio a bit wary of putting out a superhero movie with Ryan Reynolds as the leading man. Could be nonsense, but hopefully *Deadpool* has put paid to that kind of nonsense.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I have heard that too but got no proof for it yet, might dig it later.

Comment: Ryan Reynolds also just did an interview where he states that he was blackmailed to play the horrible version of Deadpool in Wolverine Origins if he ever hoped to have an independent film. He told them their version was bad, and it wasn't upon pilot testing the film and everyone hating the character that the urgently flew Ryan from Canada back to the studio to film the post credit scene with Deadpool's eyes open, a wink, and mouth not sewn shut. Because of the backlash they created, they were also hesitant. Thank "the person" that leaked the DP Test footage from ComicCon

Comment: I think that Reynolds "leaked" it

Comment: @user001 i did heard that somewhere, don't have proof fro now

Answer (score 2):

Well, another reason that might not be so obvious to some people was the fact that Ryan Reynolds had to fondle a guy's balls who's name rhymed with "Pulverine"
In the movie, Deadpool clearly states that he can't tell you who he you who balls he had to fondle ,but he does include some clues as to who's he did,

First scene in this video,

Then Ryan Reynolds discusses this in this interview,

> Q: Can you tell me what you imagine **fondling Wolverine balls feels**
>   like, b/c that played on my mind?
>
> A: Its like Santa's sack he is carrying around, that thing is is like
>   a good 15 to 16 lbs a peice

So, although it is pretty encrypted, the message is that he had to fondle Wolverines **balls**, or more specifically **Hugh Jackman's**. Which in itself was one of the main reasons it took 13 years.

Comment: I can't tell if this classifies as an 'in-universe' answer or not.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh: exactly. It’s all fun and games breaking the fourth wall, but then you realise you actually needed it intact.

Comment: @strictly in universe.

Comment: An out of universe DP answer is still an in universe DP answer. I read it in a book. ;)